# How do I troubleshoot slow wifi speed on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: wireless, 20.04, internet, downloads

I just switched from Windows to Ubuntu 20.04. My download speed went down from 30 Mbps to 1 Mbps. I can't even watch a youtube video at 720p. Are there any solutions to this? Also, I noticed after I connect to my wifi, it is fast the first 2 minutes and then it slows down again. I don't want to have to disconnect and connect to my wifi every 2 minutes.

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 05
       serial: b8:70:f4:d5:8c:bf
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-40-generic firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: 74:de:2b:2e:5c:91
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=5.11.0-40-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7c00000-f7c03fff
```

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b1d6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd CNF9055 Toshiba Webcam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I should mention I'm just a normie who switched to Linux so I can use OpenGL 3.3.

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us the make/model of the wifi adapter on your device. Info about your USB devices is not particularly helpful.  The solutions to wifi issues are generally hardware specific when there is actually a problem with software or drivers. Often, wifi *quality* issues have to do with location and/or different types of interference.

Comment: There was an Intel wifi issue like this recently, it crept into a kernel update and was fixed around the 5.12 range (I think), and supposedly may have affected other devices, did this happen after a HWE upgrade changed the kernel version from 5.8 to 5.11, or did you just install it and it has not worked since?

Comment: @RichieFrame I just installed ubuntu 2 weeks ago or so. and the problem was always here. i just didnt notice as much because its just weirdly goes and comes back, but when i turn wifi off and then on its normal speed but after some time it goes back to being slow. i dont think thats my modem or my distance from it because i didnt have this problem in windows 10 pro

Comment: @Nmath's troubleshooting method is correct. We have seen these before. Avoid asking for solutions but then eschew basic troubleshooting steps that we need to rule out possible causes. Without additional information we cannot help you.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`. What's your MTU? `ip link show`.

Comment: @Nmath thanks. the link you gave has the answer my down speed is back to normal.